# Given the following image find the angle $\beta$ in function of $\alpha$ and $\gamma$

Tags: geometry

[image]

We have the triangle ABC, the anlge $\beta$ is the one formed in AB with BC.

My textbook says "The anlge $\beta$ is half of the angle $\alpha - \gamma$.

It doesn't give any more explanation, so, why  is the angle $\beta$ half the angle $\alpha-\gamma$?

Comment: See [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the properties of angles inscribed in circles.  If you notice, $\alpha-\gamma$ is the measure of $\angle AOC$ and arc $\overset{\Large\frown}{AC}$.  This type of angle is called a *central angle* (ie, an angle whose vertex is at the center).

Another type of angle is an *inscribed angle*, an angle whose vertex is on the circle itself.  A commonly used property of such angles is that an inscribed angle is half the measure of the central angle which passes through the same arc (in this case, $\overset{\Large\frown}{AC}$).

Therefore, $\angle{ABC}$ has measure $\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}$ because it's an inscribed angle through arc $\overset{\Large\frown}{AC}$.  The fact that point B is where it is doesn't really affect the problem, as long as point B is somewhere on the circle.